# Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete? Transparent background color?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, autofill

I have a form in which the autocomplete imposes a blue background color. My form has a semi-transparent white background color. I was able to change the color of the autofill to white using this CSS property

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px white inset;
```

Unfortunately, if I set a semi-transparent color, the CSS property no longer works. Can anyone solve this problem? I also tried different properties with `!important` found here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean by "the CSS property no longer works" that the original browser autofill color is partly visible behind the new semi-transparent color (as in, the box-shadow color is acting like an overlay on the original color).

What you could do, is chain multiple box-shadows. Setting the last one as a solid color, like so:

```
:-webkit-autofill,
:-webkit-autofill:hover,
:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset, 0 0 0px 1000px #ff0000 inset;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it only sets the colour red without transparency